# doctrine2 three level inheritance model in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement a three level inheritance model with doctrine 2 like the following example:

Level 1 entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string", length=50)
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"Factura"="Factura", "NotaEntrega"="NotaEntrega", "Giro"="Giro", "FacturaNormal"="FacturaNormal", "FacturaPeriodica"="FacturaPeriodica"})
 */
class Cobro { ... }
```

Level 2 entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity 
 */
class Factura extends Cobro { ... }
```

Level 3 entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity 
 */
class FacturaNormal extends Factura { ... }
```

But when I try to create the getters and setters for the entity "Factura"...

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MiAlarma/FacturaBundle/Entity/Factura
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::nameIsMandatoryForDiscriminatorColumns() in /var/www/sf5/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php on line 1944
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I missed the `name=""` part from the `@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn` annotation. I can't see any problems with yours but it that does seem to be what Doctrine is complaining about.

Try using `var_dump()` in `ClassMetadataInfo::setDiscrimiatorColumn` to see what is being passed from your annotations to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the origin of the problem some time ago but forgot to update the post. I don't recall exactly what was wrong but I remember that it was something silly that has nothing to do whit the code posted. The code shown here works just fine. I think I should delete the question instead. Thanks anyway